# How to pass parameter to style function

Tags: openlayers, openlayers-3, openlayers-6, angular-openlayers

in the below posted code, i want to pass the parameter `keyGridsAsGeoJSON` as input to the function in `style` attribute.every time i print the value of `k` which is `var k = keyGridsAsGeoJSON` i receive the values posted below.
i expect that `k` contains values which contained in `keyGridsAsGeoJSON`.
the values in `keyGridsAsGeoJSON` are as shown in the image below.

please let me know why the contents of `k` is not as the contents of `keyGridsAsGeoJSON`

**values in `keyGridsAsGeoJSON`**
[image]

**value of k**:

```
k: RenderFeature {id_: undefined, type_: 'Polygon', flatCoordinates_: Array(10), flatInteriorPoints_: null, flatMidpoints_: null, …}
    ends_: [10]
    flatCoordinates_: (10) [738401.380994772, 6643445.99157804, 738417.2804938197, 663446.495435405, 38417.7843511839, 643430.558613589, 738401.035135203, 6643430.054756225, 73841.3809947722, 643445.99157804]
    flatInteriorPoints_: null
    flatMidpoints_: null
    id_: undefined
    properties_: {layer: 'default'}
    type_: "Polygon"
    [[Prototype]]: Object
```

**code**:

```
public visualisePolygonsAsMVTTilesOnMapWithColors(map,keyGridsAsGeoJSON,fillColor,strokeColor,text){
    var features = [];
    var iter = 0
    var k = keyGridsAsGeoJSON
    console.log("keyGridsAsGeoJSON:",keyGridsAsGeoJSON)
    keyGridsAsGeoJSON.forEach(function(keyGridAsGeoJSON) {
        let polygonGeometry = [keyGridAsGeoJSON['features'][0]['geometry']]
        polygonGeometry.forEach(function(geojson) {
            var geometry = new GeoJSON().readGeometry(geojson, {
                dataProjection: 'EPSG:4326',
                featureProjection: map.getView().getProjection()
                });
                features.push(new Feature(geometry));
            });
        });
    var vectorTile = new VectorTileLayer({
        source: new VectorTileSource({
            format: new MVT(),
            url: environment.LocalHostForTileLayerSourceAsMVTTileForZXYWS + "/{z}/{x}/{y}"
        }),
        style: function (k){
            console.log("features:",features)
            console.log("k:",k)
        }
      });
    return vectorTile;
}
```

Comment: The renderer calls the style function as it renders each feature.  k is the feature being rendered.

Comment: thanks. do you mean that even if i did not pass an parameter to the style function, still i can access each feature in it?

Comment: The style function is called by the renderer, not by your code.  Every call is passed one feature.  If you `console.log("k:",k.getProrties()) ` you will see the properties which can be used to distinguish between features and return a style specific to that feature.